# writing excel through JAVA using HSSF workBook

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf, hssf

I am using HSSF work book to write data into excel using java, Now i have a column name with n-no of words, if i insert it normally its coming in a same line, i want to break the sentences into two different line and insert into same cell.

below is the code iam using to set the column

```
 rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Hi there it is my lengthy column please help");
```

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the Java new line `'\n'` char to break your sentence into 2 lines then set `WrapText` to `true`:

```
    Cell cell = rowhead.createCell((short) 0));
    cell.setCellValue("Hi there it is my lengthy \n column please help");
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Comment: U mean i need to do like  --- ' rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Hi there it is my '\n' lengthy column please help") '

Comment: Yes but you need to apply a CellStyle with the property WrapText set to 'true' to make it works.